# Adding an appointment in HTML to an Outlook Calender

Tags: javascript, asp.net, outlook

I am trying to add an appointment to outlook through JavaScript, ASP.NET etc., any kind of language will do. I've searched all over the internet but could not manage to find an answer or anything alike.

Thanks in advance

Let me clarify.
I need to make a web-application where the user can fill in a form which is then sent to the outlook agenda of the recipient. The web-server is hosted with IIS (Internet Information Services). I have read about several things like Exchange Server and Exchange Web Services (EWS). I don't know how far either of those go with what I need. I don't know where to start any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is a very broad question, what have you tried to do so far? What problems are you encountering? You need to ask a more specific question rather than just: "I made a minimal effort to look at this myself, can you do it for me?"

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the DDay.iCal Library: http://sourceforge.net/projects/dday-ical/

It parses files in the iCalendar format and provides an object-oriented interface to iCalendar components: Event, Todo, TimeZone, Journal, FreeBusy, and Alarm. The output can be imported or subscribed to in Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

You an use iCal as Christophe suggests, but it requires the user to download an .ics or .vcs file and open it.  If you need to write directly to any of their Outlook data stores (e.g. their Exchange Mailbox or their .pst file) then you cannot do so from a web application (unless you use Exchange Web Services to write to their Mailbox).  If this is a desktop script you can use the Outlook Object Model in VBScript, VBA or a COM Add-in to create appointments.